# Missing /src and /dist in node_module (with workspaces)

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I forked a package and made some changes and need to install it locally. Here's [my branch](https://github.com/ilmoi/saber-common/tree/ilmoi_support_v0).

I ran:

```
yarn add 'saber2@https://github.com/ilmoi/saber-common#head=ilmoi_support_v0'
```

which successfully installs the package, but it's missing both /src and /dist and so it unusable.

Having searched for similar issues I unsuccessfully tried:

- building and commiting /dist dir (made sure not in .gitignore)
- adding a "files" line to package.json (both top level and inside the workspace)
- adding a "prepare" line
- adding a blank .npmignore

None of those works. Here's how the package looks in node modules:

[image]

I suspect the problem is to do with workspaces. For some reason none of them compile / show. Please advise on what I'm missing.

Comment: is the missing part is `packages` folder? it doesn't even exists when you open it in file explorer?

Comment: yeah so that entire dir doesnt exist which is why I think it's some workspace issue - I'm not experienced to tell

Comment: so.. i noticed you were using experimental feature called `workspaces` i do wonder if those dependencies already hoisted (moved) up in the file system to be under `node_modules` directory directly, see on [limitations](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/workspaces/#toc-limitations-caveats). also, it says *"Nested workspaces are not supported at this time"* which may cause tricky situation if another project that uses your package also involve use workspaces.